# What are the options for upgrading an AngularJS application to Angular before its end of life (December 2021)?

Tags: angularjs, angular

My organization has a mostly read-only web application that our clients use that's implemented in AngularJS.  Our leadership isn't keen on devoting resources to migrating that application to Angular in the next year (AngularJS will not be patched after December 2021, as I understand).  Keep in mind that, in 2022, we intend to look at a true upgrade to this application, which will be a re-write.  We are just buying time until then.  So, I'm looking for options.  Here are some of my questions around this:

1. How important is it to migrate AngularJS to Angular in the next year, before a true re-write?
2. If it is important to migrate AngularJS to Angular in the next year, are there any "short cuts"?  I've seen some tools, but I can't tell how effective they are.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your app won't magically stop working, so that completely depends on what browser features your app needs and when those become deprecated (if at all).
2. No. Unless your app is extremely simple, the upgrade path is gonna be a non-trivial amount of work. How much work again completely depends on size and complexity your app.

To clarify on the the shortcut options (#2), you can make your app hybrid (ng1 and ng2+ side-by-side) but all that does is allow you to upgrade piecemeal. It still requires converting ng1 modules to ng2+. You also have to consider your build, hosting, and development process which is more overhead compared to a full rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  Concerning #1, I think the principle concern is that security updates will stop.  I'm not sure how to assess that risk.  Are there a lot of security issues that have come up with AngularJS in the past that needed to be patched?  Any thoughts on that would be welcome.

Comment: The last security update was on 2020-06-01 to AngularJS v1.8 see the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for details.